# Curl post with multipart/form-data and JSON

Tags: linux, curl, multipartform-data

Is there a way to use curl to do a `multipart/form-data` post and specify that the data is `application/json`?  It doesn't have to be curl.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is what I use, and it works fine

```
curl -v -H "Content-Type:multipart/form-data" 
        -F "someName={\"your\":\"json\"};type=application/json"
```

Note: I'm on Windows, hence the requirement for double quotes

Or

```
-F "someName=@someJsonFile.json;type=application/json"
```

Comment: I just have to ask, is this bad design? I feel like this is my only option but it seems fishy to me.

Comment: @LostAtSea What's fishy about it?

Comment: I'm weary of passing a JSON string in form data, it seems like bad design. Then I'll have to go parse the entire JSON string in my application into an object. This forces the client to have to know the expected structure of a string, which isn't straightforward to advertise. I'm just wondering if there are any other options, since I've never seen this used before.

Comment: @LostAtSea The second one lets you pass a file. And _you_ are the client if you're talking about using curl, so I'm not really sure what the issue is. Your argument makes more sense if you're developing an API. Most clients using multipart aren't going to be using curl anyway

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified. I _am_ writing an API, and I'm also developing the front end application to consume it. So I'm looking for something a bit more robust. But if this is my only option, so be it.