# parsing 'multipart-data' using express

Tags: javascript, json, express, multipartform-data, body-parser

I have this weird issue of parsing the data from the client.

I found that all the 'boolean true' were converted to 'string true and same for 'undefined' and hence i cannot do a 'if' on those fields.

Here is what I have:

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();
app.post('/someroute',function(req,res,next){
   console.log(typeof req.someBooleanValue);
});
```

I always get 'string' and i am expecting boolean in console because that's what the client sent.

Now it works fine if the content-type is set to 'application/json'

I understand that body parser won't work with 'multipart' content type. But then what are my options? I tried multiparty and multr. But post parsing with them, I still get the fields as the strings.

Is there no other way to handle this than to write a small utility which checks the content type and then do some ugly stripping of quotes using JSON.parse('fields') or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using [Busboy](https://github.com/mscdex/busboy) for a REST application with express.js, to handle file upload, in multipart/form-data and it's working fine.

Examples are available on the page of the project.
Just a warning, if you need to handle file upload, make sure you have a listener for the `'finish'` event of the WriteableStream use to save the file and that you do not rely exclusively on the `'finish'` event raised by busboy itself.

Comment: Nope. This doesn't work. It still comes as 'string' not as boolean

Answer (score 0):

It (sort-of) depends on the client.

AFAIK, `multipart/form-data` parts uploaded through `<form>` elements (by a browser) aren't typed: they either contain textual (string) content (for "regular" fields) or binary content (for "file" fields).

In other words, all the fields that your serverside parser will provide you with are going to be strings. Without some explicit code, multer/multiparty/etc have no idea that a string value of `true` is meant to be a boolean, so you're going to have to perform some conversion/casting yourself, based on the knowledge of what each field should contain.

If you're using a CLI client like cURL, you can upload JSON "files" as separate parts (explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29563907/curl-post-with-multipart-form-data-and-json)). You would still need to call `JSON.parse()` on the incoming data, because it will still be passed as a string.

Comment: So how it is handled usually? I tried doing JSON.parse on req.body but it fails ridiculously because req.body is already a JSON object

Comment: @beNerd do you need file upload capabilities? If so, you are stuck with `multipart/formdata`. If not, you can use [`body-parser`](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser) to upload as JSON directly (and `req.body` will be the _parsed_ object)

Comment: I do need file upload as well but it's kinda optional in my form. I use body-parser but i am having trouble with true/false/undefined values. All of these gets converted to strings and I can't do any comparisons server side.

Comment: @beNerd if you are uploading proper JSON, `body-parser` should provide you with the proper types. It means you need to upload the data as `application/json`, too, and not URL-encoded (because that would convert everything to a string).